# docker desktop is loading container under a folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm newbie in docker, and I'm using docker desktop, my goal is to deploy an angular app, here is my dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1: Compile and Build angular codebase

# Create the node starge with the name "build"
FROM node:latest as build
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app
# Copy files from current directory to working directory
COPY . .
# Install all the dependencies and build all assets.
# In case of npm errors because of peer dependencies use npm run ng build --force or with --legacy-peer-deps
RUN npm i && npm run build:prod

# Stage 2: Serve app with nginx server

# Create the nginx stage for serving content
FROM nginx:alpine
# Set the working directory to nginx asset directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
# Remove default static assets
RUN rm -rf ./*
# Copy static assets as a result of builder stage from the folder
# "/app/dist/client/es", into the working directory
COPY --from=build /app/dist/client/es/ .
# Containers run nginx with global directives and daemon off
ENTRYPOINT [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

Here's my docker-compose:

```
services:
  vitalixclientapp:
    container_name: App_Client
    build: .
    image: vitalixclientapp:v1
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    expose:
      - 4200
    networks:
      - internal_network

networks:
  internal_network:
    driver: bridge
```

When a build the docker-compose it creates the image and the container, however I don't understand why is creating a folder in the container, as showqn in the picture below. I tried by changing the output path of the build process to a single folder called dist, but non success. How can I do to avoid that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a presentation detail within the Docker Desktop application, which has special awareness of Compose setups.

Docker otherwise doesn't have any notion of "folder", and Docker proper doesn't actually have any knowledge that different containers might be related in some way.  If you don't use the Docker Desktop application (maybe you're on a native-Linux host and don't need it; maybe you're using another setup like a Kubernetes Minikube VM as your primary Docker environment) then these "folders" don't exist at all.